Making Script only send to an email once?
So I have a Script working and once I press the associated button it sends an email to a list from pulled data, I have an issue though as the list is constantly updated and the script will be run multiple times but i don't want it to send to emails it has already sent to previously, is there any way to ensure this or will i have to think of another solution?
This is the Code:
function myFunction2() {
  let sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  let data = sheet.getRange('A2:B').getDisplayValues();
  data.filter(row => row.every(Boolean)).forEach(row => {
    let [name, address] = row;
    let subject = `Your RSVP is Confirmed!`;
    let body = `<b>Dear ${name}.</b><br><br> 

Thank you for RSVPing <b>YES</b> More Text Here.<br><br> 

<b>Event Details:</b><br><br>

<b>Date:</b> Text Here<br><br>

<b>Time:</b> Text Here<br><br>

Here's what you can look forward to:<br><br>

<b>Exclusive Open Bar:</b> Enjoy a carefully selected drinks menu with premium beverages.<br>
<b>Gourmet Sushi:</b> Indulge in a variety of delicious sushi offerings.<br>
<b>DJ:</b> Live entertainment <br><br>

Line of Text Here.<br><br>

We can't wait to celebrate this special night with you and showcase the exciting future of our venture!<br><br>

Line of text Here<br><br>



<b>Warm Regards,</b><br><br>
<img src="Image Here" alt="Image 1" style="width: 167px; height: 105px;", ALIGN="Left" HSPACE="25">
<span style='color: #C19B77;'Text Here</span><br>
<b><span style='color: #C19B77; font-size: 15px;'>Text here</span></b><br><br>
<b><span style='color: #000000;'>Mobile:</b> Text Here &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; Text Here<br>
<b><span style='color: #000000;'>Email:</b> Text Here&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; Text Here<br>
<b>URL:</b> Text Here&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; Text Here `;
  
    MailApp.sendEmail({to: address, subject, htmlBody: body, cc:''});
  });
}


I'm Honestly not sure what to try as this is unknown to me.

I am not sure how google apps script works. But what makes sense to me is to have an extra column to represent if the email has been sent. If so, you just do not send the email; and otherwise you set the cell to true and send the email

use column C (as checkbox) for keeping track if email was sent:
function myFunction2() {
  let sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  let dataRange = sheet.getRange('A2:C');
  let data = dataRange.getValues(); // Get values from columns A, B, and C

  data.forEach((row, index) => {
    let [name, address, emailSent] = row;

    // Skip rows where any cell in columns A or B is empty or where column C is TRUE
    if (!name || !address || emailSent === true) return;

    let subject = `Your RSVP is Confirmed!`;
    let body = `<b>Dear ${name}.</b><br><br> 

Thank you for RSVPing <b>YES</b> More Text Here.<br><br> 

<b>Event Details:</b><br><br>

<b>Date:</b> Text Here<br><br>

<b>Time:</b> Text Here<br><br>

Here's what you can look forward to:<br><br>

<b>Exclusive Open Bar:</b> Enjoy a carefully selected drinks menu with premium beverages.<br>
<b>Gourmet Sushi:</b> Indulge in a variety of delicious sushi offerings.<br>
<b>DJ:</b> Live entertainment <br><br>

Line of Text Here.<br><br>

We can't wait to celebrate this special night with you and showcase the exciting future of our venture!<br><br>

Line of text Here.<br><br>

<b>Warm Regards,</b><br><br>
<img src="Image Here" alt="Image 1" style="width: 167px; height: 105px;", ALIGN="Left" HSPACE="25">
<span style='color: #C19B77;'>Text Here</span><br>
<b><span style='color: #C19B77; font-size: 15px;'>Text here</span></b><br><br>
<b><span style='color: #000000;'>Mobile:</b> Text Here &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; Text Here<br>
<b><span style='color: #000000;'>Email:</b> Text Here&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; Text Here<br>
<b>URL:</b> Text Here&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; Text Here `;

    // Send the email
    MailApp.sendEmail({to: address, subject, htmlBody: body, cc: ''});

    // Mark email as sent in column C
    sheet.getRange(index + 2, 3).setValue(true); // +2 because index is 0-based and data starts from row 2
  });
}


Perfect, that worked immediately thankyou!
